What method to use to measure incrementality (lift) on a group with different intervention dates (bayesian)?
I have 2 groups (test and control).
I want to measure the impact of my intervention in the test group.
Notes:

This is a time-series question

Test and control group are NOT equal in number. The test group is smaller.

Each intervention (on the test) have happened at different time.

The goal is to measure incrementality and not just the difference


Work done already:

We could potentially not use the control but in our case, we want to utilize the control sample and prove incrementality
Causal impact analysis: We can use the Causal impact analysis framework by google but our sample size has +300 samples.

I have tried Causal impact analysis and results make sense but now I want to scale the method and include a bigger sample size (+500) so i can't do all of them manually.

This seems more like a stats question than a programming one to me?
